# how to syncronize datetime field in Codeigniter and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

i'm working with Codeigniter and Mysql for database.
on of my table have one field called **tgl_input** with type **TIMESTAMP**.
for that field my form in Codeigniter look like this

```
<input type="text" name="ti" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d h:m") ?>" hidden="true">
```

this for my *controller*

```
'tgl_input' => $this->input->post('ti'),
```

and usual code using activerecord in my *model*
when i tried to input in 9:47AM, data is inputed with datetime today, 04:07. i didn't know whats wrong, this is my first time using datetime field in Codeigniter and Mysql. i'm in timezone +7 Bangkok, Jakarta btw

Comment: Are you just taking a calculated input from the client side? That seems a bit sloppy. Why not just let mysql handle the timestamp for you?

Comment: should i delete this value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d h:m") form my view? @Difster

Comment: that's not client side, php is server side ,but i would the MySQL function NOW()

Comment: @Kiki, yes, you won't need that hidden field if you're just using mysql to calculate the timestamp input.

Comment: @rtfm. It's being shown on the client side as a hidden input and then served back to PHP, so yes, it's client side.

Comment: do you want to fix time zone in your website as Asia/Bangkok or want this input as per client side time zone?

Comment: nothing change when i delete that part @Difster

Comment: yes i want to fix time zone as Asia/Bangkok for all user

Comment: thats one odd definition of client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this in controller itself

`'tgl_input' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),`

Answer (score 0):

'tgl_input' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($this->input->post('ti'))),